# Laravel polymorphic relations: Passing model to controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, polymorphism

I want to use a single controller to save my comments for multiple models. So I created the CommentController, with the following store method:

```
public function store(Teacher $teacher, Request $request)
    {    
        $input = $request->all();

        $comment = new Comment();

        $comment->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $comment->body = $input['body'];

        $teacher->comments()->save($comment);

        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

In my view, I have:

```
{!! Form::open([
    'route' => ['teachers.comments.store', $teacher->id]
]) !!}
```

This is working. If I want to use the same CommentController to store the comments for a school, how should I modify the store method of the controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im not sure if this is the Laravel convension, but i have done the following:

Made a route:

```
Route::post('/Comment/{model}/{id}', [
    // etc
]);
```

Then in the controller get the model and check against an array of allowed models, pass the id through and attach:

```
public function store(Request $request, $model, $id) {
    $allowed = ['']; // list all models here

    if(!in_array($model, $allowed) {
        // return redirect back with error
    }

    $comment = new Comment();
    $comment->user_id = $request->user()->id;
    $comment->commentable_type = 'App\\Models\\'.$model;
    $comment->commentable_id = $id;
    $comment->body = $request->body;
    $comment->save();

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Like I say, there is most likely a much better way to accomplish, but this is how I've done it. It keeps it short and sweet and checks if the model can take a comment.

Comment: thank you for the solutions! I had to change `'App\\Models\\' . $model;` to `'App\\' . $model;`

Comment: Ah yes sorry, i usually put all my models in a Models directory. Glad it worked for you :)

Comment: Ugliest thing I have ever seen in my life... And this is the accepted answer? :D

Answer (score 5):

Adam's solution is great, but I would not hard-code the model's namespace that way. Instead, what I would do is make use of Laravel's `Relation::morphMap()`, you can check it out here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations

That way, you will also make your database entries more readable. I recommend using a service provider to map the morphs.

Also, the `Model` base class has a `getMorphClass()` method, so instead of

`$comment->commentable_type = 'App\\Models\\'.$model;`

I would use

`$comment->commentable_type = $model->getMorphClass();`

That way you integrate Laravel's logic into your code.

Answer (score 2):

I implemented this way if you want, according to me it's the one of the bests way to do that.

```
// Route::post('/comments/{model}/{id}', 'CommentController@store');
class CommentController extends Controller {

protected $model;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->model = Relation::getMorphedModel(
        request()->route()->parameter('model')
    );
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    dd($this->model); // return 'App\Post' or null
}

}
```

Comment: What model is `Relation`? Do you mean `Comment`?

Comment: The Relation Model is `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation`