# Laravel Updating Polymorphic Relations

Tags: laravel, polymorphism

Let's say I have 3 tables, `Events`, `Matches` and `Training`. `Events` is a polymorphic table, it can be either `Match` or `Training`.

```
------------------    -----------    --------------
|  Events        |    | Matches |    | Trainings  |
------------------     ----------    --------------
| id             |    | id      |    | id         |
| name           |    | home    |    | type       |
| eventable_id   |    | away    |    --------------    
| eventable_type |    -----------
------------------
```

Now, I create an event like this:

```
$match = Match::create(['home' => Team 1', 'away' => 'Team 2']);
$match->events()->create(['name' => 'Event name']);
```

Therefore I have this record in my `Events` table:

```
--------------------------------------
| 1 | 'Event name' | 1 | 'App\Match' |
--------------------------------------
```

And in `Matches`:

```
---------------------------
| 1 | 'Team 1' | 'Team 2' |
---------------------------
```

My `Event Model`:

```
public function eventable() {
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

My `Match/Training Model`:

```
public function events() {
    return $this->morphMany('App\Event', 'eventable');
}
```

However, what if I want to update **that Event** and I want to change it from `Match` To `Training` but keep the event.

Is there a more Eloquent way or do I have to do it like this ?

```
$event->eventable->delete();
$training = Training::create(['type' => 'Stamina Training']);
$event->update([
    'name' => $request->name,
    'eventable_id' => $training->id,
    'eventable_type' => 'App\Training'
]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Alright, I also faced the same issue and the solution is to use the associate function on the relation. Instead of deleting the "eventable" on the "event", you can simply associate another model instance to the morph relationship. like below.

```
$training = Training::create(['type' => 'Stamina Training']);
$event->eventable()->associate($training);
$event->update([
    'name' => $request->name
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by following the same convention on this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40388570/laravel-polymorphic-relations-passing-model-to-controller). It's not a Laravel way but it could do the trick.