# Laravel polymorphic as Archive

Tags: laravel, polymorphism, archive

I have a polymorphic relationship and need a feature where I can save posts and comments in a table for an archive.

I want to use the code from [Laravel polymorphic relations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40388570/laravel-polymorphic-relations-passing-model-to-controller/48708048?noredirect=1#comment84418244_48708048) 
what should I insert in the middle at the????????????

```
    public function store(Request $request, $model, $id) {
    $allowed = ['Post','Comment']; // list all models here

    if(!in_array($model, $allowed){

    ???????????????????????????????????
    }

    $archive = new Archive();
    $archive->user_id = $request->user()->id;
    $archive->archiveable_type = 'App\\' . $model;
    $archive->archiveable_id = $id;
    $archive->save();

    return back()->with('success', lang::get('messages.newarchive'));
}
```

Comment: what exactly do yo u want ?

Comment: I have edited my post

Comment: I can't understand what are you trying to achieve exactly, are you trying to implement polymorphic relationships? If so, why are you posting code from your controller then?

Comment: I want to create an archive for the user in which he can save posts and comments to watch later. I gelsen in internet that I need for a polymorphic relationship. I do not know how I can save the data exactly in the archive table.