# Laravel - Polymorphic relationships for model types

Tags: laravel, postgresql, model-view-controller, polymorphism

I'm new in Laravel and as my first project I'm trying to make a survey API.

I'm struggling to create a model and controller for answer types, after looking it up about my issue I found out about polymorphic relationships and that somewhat fulfills what I need. Adam Watham made a good video about model and model types but it doesn't speak about creating it.

**Link for the video:**https://adamwathan.me/2015/09/03/pushing-polymorphism-to-the-database/

## MODELS

I created a model for answers and answer types and had to add an attribute type on **Answers** because I have to know what type it is beforehand. I chose to add morphTo on the type model because I want none or many **Types(text,number)** on my answer:

```
class NumberAnswer extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'number'
    ];

    public function numberable()
    {
        $this->morphTo();
    }
}

class TextAnswer extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'text'
    ];

    public function textable()
    {
        $this->morphTo();
    }
}

class Answer extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'question_id',
        'type'
    ];

    public function numbers()
    {
        $this->morphMany('App\Models\File', 'numberable');
    }

    public function texts()
    {
        $this->morphMany('App\Models\Text', 'textable');
    }
}
```

What I'm having trouble is with how to store them, how I'm doing currently and where I found some tips:

[Polymorphic controller solution that I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40388570/laravel-polymorphic-relations-passing-model-to-controller)

## Service Provider

```
public function boot()
{
    Relation::morphMap([
        'answer' => 'App\Models\Answer'
    ]);
}
```

## AnswerController

```
class AnswerController extends Controller
{
    private $answer;


    public function __construct(AnswerRepository $answerRepo)
    {
        $this->answer = $answerRepo;
    }

    public function store(Request $request, int $tenantId)
    {
       $requestAnswer = $request->validate([
         'user_id' => [
            'required',
            'numeric',
            Rule::exists('users','id'),
        ],
        'question_id' => [
            'required',
            'numeric',
            Rule::exists('questions','id'),
        ],
        'type' => [
            'required',
            'in:text,number'
        ]
       ]);

       $text = $request->validate([
           'text' => 'required_if:type,text|string',
       ]);
       $number = $request->validate([
           'number' => 'required_if:type,number|string',
       ]);

       $answer = $this->answer->create($requestAnswer);

       if($requestAnswer['type'] === 'text'){
          $answer->texts()->create(['text' => $text]);
       }
       if($requestAnswer['type'] === 'number'){
          $answer->numbers()->create(['number' => $number]);
       }

       return response()->json($answer);
    }

}
```

## QUESTION

I'm a little lost about what should I do because as I'm learning I wish to know if there is another way I'm not seeing. There is a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Once you setup the polymorphic relation, it acts like a normal relationship of its kind. So you're using a morph many to many, it works the same as the regular many to many for all of the methods.

Finally, you might want to consider storing your answer as the JSON column type. In your specific use case, it seems more appropriate.

Comment: I want to make more types of answer like files which I want to use in another part of the system. Thanks to your answer now I understand that I don't need to do a polymorphic relationship when I'm not going to need to use the same model in other places and about the JSON column type I don't like about the idea of dealing with it afterwards.

Answer (score -2):

I may be speaking out of turn, and am not coming from a Laravel background. Coming from a RDBMS background, polymorphic relationships are a **red flag**. That doesn't mean they're always a bad design (that would be too easy), but they're inherently problematic. Mainly, because a lot of the relational integrity controls you can get declaratively, and for "free" in an RDBMS are thrown out. Then again, polymorphic relations tend to come up in cases where the relational model is an awkward fit. (Kind of relations.) I use such relations from time to time, but rarely....and with a lot of thought in advance.  I guess that promiscuous relations are baked into Laravel, so Laravel may have overcome a lot of the problems for you already somehow. (As noted, I haven't a clue.) And if Postgres is just a persistance mechanism for Laravel, maybe it doesn't matter so much.

You didn't ask about polymorphic relations per se, so I'll leave it at that. But if you're interested in the subject, Bill Karwin's chapter on the topic in SQL Anitpatterns is quite good.